# Require Instance of Class to Override a Method

Tags: java

Here's the situation: I have a class and I create instances of. I'd like it to inherit the majority of the methods/variables in the class, but I want a few methods to be required to be overridden, similar to how an abstract class works.

Here is my code so far.

```
public class Example {
    public void methodOne() {
        //Inherited
    }
    public void methodTwo() {
        //Interited
        //Maybe calls methodThree() as a part of its function
    }
    public void methodThree() {
        //Override Me
    }
}
```

Comment: So make it abstract.

Comment: I take it that you can't make it abstract because you create instances of this class?

Comment: @SLaks As mentioned in the question, I can't because I need to create instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't [make the class abstract] because I need to create instances

Making the class abstract does prevent instantiation, but since you want to prevent instantiation unless a method is overridden, this is the right thing to do.

You can make overrides anonymously, so syntactically this would be similar to instantiating the base class:

```
public abstract class Example {
    public void methodOne() {
        //Inherited
    }
    public void methodTwo() {
        //Interited
        //Maybe calls methodThree() as a part of its function
    }
    public abstract void methodThree();
}
...
static void main(String[] args) {
    Example e = new Example() {
        @Override
        public void methodThree() {
            ... // Do something
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: So you can create an instance variable of an abstract class as long as it overrides all abstract methods/variables, correct?

Comment: @AllenF. That's the thing -- it's no longer an abstract class that you are instantiating. This syntax produces an anonymous class derived from `Example`, but since it overrides the abstract method, the anonymous class is no longer abstract.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *requiring* people to write code in a particular way can be counter productive.  Someone may have a legitimate use-case (*that you had not considered !!*) for dong it differently, and your restriction may force them to solve the problem in a way that makes things significantly worse than if your restriction wasn't there.  Bear this in mind ...

But here's a solution:

```
public abstract class ExampleBase  {
    public void methodOne() {
        // Inherited
    }

    public void methodTwo() {
        // Interited
        // Maybe calls methodThree() as a part of its function
    }

    public abstract void methodThree();
}

public final class Example  {
    @Override
    public void methodThree() {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

We have solved the problem by moving all of the members that you want to inherit to an abstract superclass.  Any methods that you want to force people to override are declared as `abstract`.  By declaring your concrete `Example` class as `final`, we prevent them from circumventing your requirement and subclassing `Example` without overriding `methodThree`.